# "is allowed multiple installs, skipping" prevents downgrade of kernel on Centos6

Tags: centos6, yum, rpm

I have **2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64** installed and would like to downgrade to **2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64** but the following command results in a skipping message:

```
yum downgrade -y --disableexcludes=all  kernel-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Setting up Downgrade Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package kernel-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64 is allowed multiple installs, skipping
```

I cannot uninstall the current kernel via yum (as I could do via apt) and nor can I use rpm to easily do the work as there are some dependencies to sort out, which is why I chose to use yum in the first place.

So, is there an option to get yum to not skip and run the installation so I can use grubby to switch kernels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yum install`, not `yum downgrade`, on packages which can have multiple versions installed. The lowest version package of the same name will be removed if the number of versions has exceeded `installonly_limit`. You can also `yum remove` a specific package version if you wish (but avoid removing the running kernel; this usually results in an unbootable system).

Comment: oh because I'm changing a variant within a version, it is not really a downgrade.  Ah, ok that makes sense